# How to reuse Type returned value to generate new source code

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have this problem:

I want to generate a new source code file from a object information.

I make something like this:

dictParamMapping is a `Dictionary<string, Type>` where the string is a variable name and Type is the type of that variable.

I get the type to build new code using:

```
dictParamMapping[pairProcess.Value].Type.Name (or FullName)
```

When Type is int, string, datatable etc... everything works fine but when it is a dictionary, list or any other like that it returns something like:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

Which is not correct to build that new source code. I would like to get something like `Dictionary<int, double>`

Can any one help me?

Comment: Have you looked into [`GetGenericTypeDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx) and [`GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx)?

Comment: So you want to get C# alias for primitive types?

Comment: To abatishchev: Yes, thats the idea.
To O. R. Mapper: GetGenericArguments returns me the type of inside type but when a data structure like Dictionary<int, List<int>> forces me to create a recursive function to detect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to want to get a C#-compatible name from a `System.Type`. You can do this with the [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) class.

```
var typeReference = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(Dictionary<int, double>));

using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
    Console.WriteLine(provider.GetTypeOutput(typeReference));
```

Output:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, double>
```

Note that this is not guaranteed to always provide you with a valid type-name. In particular, compiler-generated types (such as for closures) will typically have type-names that are invalid in C#.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the ideal way of generating source code in .NET. 
There are officially supported ways of doing it.

The API exposed by the framework is called [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx). You can explore the documentation and samples to get an idea of what it can do. [Here's a startup sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404245.aspx), showing how to generate a class. CodeDOM supports both C# and VB.NET as output languages.